# Why would a class not find a publicly declared method?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a game in cocos2d that has a Mole Class and the Layer that calls it.  The Mole class calls this:

```
-(void)gotHit {
    [self.parent processMoleHit];
}
```

Whereas the Layer has this method declared and implemented:

```
-(void) processMoleHit;


-(void) processMoleHit {
    currentScore++;
    [self setCurrentScore];
}
```

Why would cocos2d be giving me the warning:

Instance method -processMoleHit not found (return type defaults to id).

Here is the implementation of parent, the layer class:

```
//Interface
@interface Ch3_SavingDataPlist : SimpleTimedGameRecipe
{   
    NSMutableArray *moles;
    int tagCount;
    int moleCount;
    CCSprite *mallet;
    CGPoint malletPosition;
}

-(CCLayer*) runRecipe;
-(void) step;
-(void) initBackground;
-(void) createMoleAtPosition:(CGPoint)point withZ:(float)z;
-(void) processMoleHit;

-(void) addHiScoresToMenu;
-(void) loadHiScores;
-(void) addHiScore;
-(void) deleteHiScores;
-(void) startNewGame;
-(void) gameOver;
-(void) step:(ccTime)delta;
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end
```

Comment: Cocos2D would not give this warning for any reason. Instead, the **compiler** would. And the reason is perhaps a missing header file inclusion.

Comment: Yeah, i meant xcode, not cocos2d.  And Mole does import Layer.

Comment: But is your pointer in Mole typed to be a Layer, and not an id or an NSObject or some such?

Comment: Is there an `implementation` block in a header, does that block contain a declaration of `processMoleHit` and does the file with `gotHit` include that header?

Comment: Show us the declaration of "parent".

Comment: @HotLicks I just added the declaration of parent.

Comment: You didn't give us the definition of "self.parent".  For all we can tell it's a UITableView.

Comment: My Ch3_SavingDataPlist is of class SimpleTimedGameRecipe, which is of class Recipe, which is of class CCLayer. And it is Ch3_SavingDataPlist which calls `Mole *mole = [Mole spriteWithSpriteFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"mole_normal.png"]];`
 & then `[self addChild:mole];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing type casting. Replace your code by following way:

```
-(void)gotHit {
    [(YOUR_LAYER_CLASS)self.parent processMoleHit];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you missed to include the class Mole in the target membership in XCode.

To check it select the Mole Class .m on the left side of XCode and verify that the checkbox is checked for your target on the right side of XCode, under section Target Membership. If not, it could cause that problem.